# How to stop the jittering on the circles when hovering

Tags: html, css

I have created a basic menu with years on the top and a circle below. When hovering over the li the font size is increased but this seems to be causing a wobble or jitter on the circle below.

How do I stop this and have smooth effect on hover? I have included my css and html in a code snippet so you can see what I am talking about.

```css
#timeline ul {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 5%;
    max-width: 140px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: alternate-gothic-no-3-d,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#timeline ul .hovered, #timeline ul li:hover {
    transition: all .5s;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
}

#timeline ul li .indicator {
    display: block;
}

#timeline ul li .title:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 3px solid #a39688;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
<ul class="timeline-list">
                                    <li class="" data-number="1">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="2">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="hovered" data-number="3">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="4">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="5">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="6">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="7">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="8">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="9">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="10">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="11">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                  
                                </ul>
                                
                                </div>
```

Comment: If you remove the padding on hover, it will smooth out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to made the `.title` absolute as i did in the code

```css
#timeline ul {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span.title {
     position: absolute;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
bottom: 20px;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 5%;
    max-width: 140px;
    padding: 25px 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: alternate-gothic-no-3-d,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 80px;
}

#timeline ul .hovered, #timeline ul li:hover {
    transition: all .5s;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 21px;
}

#timeline ul li .indicator {
    display: block;
}

#timeline ul li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 3px solid #a39688;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
<ul class="timeline-list">
                                    <li class="" data-number="1">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="2">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="hovered" data-number="3">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="4">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="5">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="6">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="7">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="8">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="9">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="10">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                    <li class="" data-number="11">
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                        <span class="title">1861</span>
                    </li>
                                  
                                </ul>
                                
                                </div>
```

Comment: thanks that is better but there is still a jitter on the text.

Comment: @user794846 , thanks dont forget to upvote it and mark it as helpful with the check.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

- `inline blocks` don't like whitespace between them
- add `vertical-align: top;` to the css of `ul li`
- the main problem is you're trying to substitute font-size for padding. In the normal `li` it is **25px padding + 20px font + 25px padding**, in the hover it is **12px padding + 35px font**.
- the solution: remove all the padding, and only add `line-height: 75px` to the css of `ul li`

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5kehcos6/)